# Построковый перебор данных с агрегатным подзапросом

Tags: postgresql

```
select * from t where id in (select id from t where id < (select min(id) from t) + 10);
```

Запрос долго выполняется, хотя выборка идет по индексированному полю. Причина:

```
Hash Join  (cost=593776.65..2517878.88 rows=8576786 width=290) (actual time=3120.660..15031.631 rows=1 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (t.id = t_1.id)
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Result  (cost=0.62..0.63 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.016..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
       InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
         ->  Limit  (cost=0.58..0.62 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
               ->  Index Only Scan using t_pkey on t t_2  (cost=0.58..6545674.64 rows=26876428 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (id IS NOT NULL)
                     Heap Fetches: 1
   ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..1478457.41 rows=25522671 width=290) (actual time=0.337..9863.729 rows=34165184 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=389712.31..389712.31 rows=8576786 width=8) (actual time=111.828..111.830 rows=1 loops=1)
     Buckets: 8388608  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 65537kB
     ->  Index Only Scan using t_pkey on t t_1  (cost=0.78..769872.98 rows=9781784 width=8) (actual time=111.826..111.826 rows=1 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (id < ($1 + 10))
           Heap Fetches: 1
 Planning Time: 0.927 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 13
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.833 ms, Inlining 25.898 ms, Optimization 51.166 ms, Emission 34.605 ms, Total 112.503 ms
 Execution Time: 15035.509 ms
```

Почему постгрес не кеширует результат внутреннего подзапроса? Почему используется построчный перебор? Интересует не решение а причина. Спасибо!

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вывод explain запроса, индексы используемые на поле.

Comment: Вот откуда эта привычка - городить кучу вложенных подзапросов вместо быстрых, логичных и понятных честных JOIN? Я уж не говорю про то, что самый внешний подзапрос - ну очевидно лишний...

Comment: Полный план добавил, id здесь ключ

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE id < ( SELECT MIN(id) + 10
             FROM t )
```

Comment: Спасибо, но меня интересует причина полного сканирования

Comment: @JavaJunior *меня интересует причина полного сканирования* Потому что 2 уровня вложенности - очевидно же.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста при чем 2 уровня вложенности тут?

Comment: @JavaJunior Парсер "не видит сквозь подзапрос", а потому обрабатывает самый внутренний запрос как коррелированный.

Comment: В данном примере коррелированный это агрегатный селекст? Для какой выборки он будет коррелированный, тое для каких строк он будет выполняться повторно?

Comment: @JavaJunior *коррелированный это агрегатный селект?* Коррелированный - это коррелированный, и никакого отношения к агрегации не имеет. *для каких строк он будет выполняться повторно?* Для всех, само собой. Хочешь кэширования на именно таком запросе - вытаскивай подзапрос в CTE, например.

Comment: В CTE не поможет, будет то же, проверял, и с крос джойном тоже. Вопрос был в том, что для каких строк будет повторно вычисляться min, ведь в этом и есть суть коррелированного запроса

Comment: @JavaJunior https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=45b0a3b806ecc59872a79f2cae29d5f5

Comment: Спасибо за примеры, но ситуацию это не спасает, как и писал выше, с СТЕ такие же задержки в выполнении.